# How to scale Docker containers hosted on AWS ECS programmatically?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, microservices, scale, amazon-ecs

I have created a microservice cluster on AWS ECS with four microservices, each one with its Docker images. But looking in the ESC cli I cannot find a way to scale these images.

My goal is to create an application responsible to scale this microservice, but I could not find a way to execute it, does anyone has any clue how can I scale the images?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you deploy them each as a separate ECS service? Do you have separate ECS task definitions for each of them?

Comment: Hello Mark, yes, each one has its own service and task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the "desired count" in the ECS service. You would do this programmatically through the `UpdateService` API.

Comment: Hello Mark, I appreciate your reply, I will check this API, regards!